proceed to the next cell based on conditions met when the cell value reaches the value from another cell
In cell A1 I have a product code, lets say 2130 cell in cell B1 we have the quantity for that product lets say 3500 pcs. I would like to have excel add to another sheet where it meets the same code to the cell. lets say on another sheet we have cell B4 with the code 2130 at C4 we have a quantity of 2300. I want excel to fill in cell D4 with the quantity of CA and proceed to check other cells to fill in.
I have been trying with out success

Hi Mark, I am using If and I am trying to fill in several cells when values are met from a single cell containing a big  "value". Does this say something? I want excel to fill in the cell based on the value of another cell then proceed to the next cell when conditions are met and continue to the next cell and so on

Product Code quantity required Target Quantity  Product Code  Stock (pcs)
601299                                       306                      601299   3000
603466                                       360                      603466   250
601603                                       360                      601603   160
603466                                       360                      602489   750
601299                                       306
602489                                       275

Can I upload an excel file?

I think CA is a typo. Other than that, I advise to use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to be able to post your data as data in your question (using the edit function). Please make sure to add an expected result with sample data.
